# The indecomposable projective $\mathbb{F}_pG$-module with $UJ/J\cong \mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: finite-groups, modules, projective-module

Let:

1. $G$ be a finite group;
2. $p$ be prime;
3. $J$ be the Jacobson radical of $\mathbb{F}_pG$.

A paper I'm trying to read mentions the following object:

> The indecomposable projective $\mathbb{F}_pG$-module $U$ with $U/UJ\cong\mathbb{F}_p$

It is then also claimed that $U$ is a direct summand of $\mathbb{F}_pG$.

> 1. Why does this object exist?
> 2. Why is it unique?
> 3. Why is it a direct summand of $\mathbb{F}_pG$.

I know all the definitions of the terms mentioned, but not experienced with some of them.

The paper is "The Presentation Rank of a Direct Product of Finite Groups" / Cossey, Gruenberg, Kovacs (Journal Of Alegebra 28, 597-603 (1974)).

**EDIT**: If relevant, it might be understood from context that $p$ divides $|G|$, but I'm nore sure.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{F}_p[G]$ is Artinian, $\mathbb{F}_p[G]/J$ is semisimple Artinian.  Hence every submodule of $\mathbb{F}_p[G]/J$ is a direct summand.  In particular $\mathbb{F}_p\subseteq \mathbb{F}_p[G]/J$ is the image of an idempotent $e\in \mathbb{F}_p[G]/J$.  By the descending chain condition and Nakayama's lemma, $J$ is nilpotent.  Hence we can lift $e$ to an idempotent $\hat{e}\in \mathbb{F}_p[G]$.  The image of $\hat{e}$ is probably the module you want.  Unfortunately, it isn't clear how this approach gives uniqueness.

Comment: Alternatively: every simple module $S$ has a projective cover $P$ which is a direct summand of $\mathbb{F}_pG$, and is such that $P/PJ \cong S$.  Furthermore the multiplicity of $P$ as a direct summand of $\mathbb{F}_pG$ is $\dim S$.  I'd recommend you read something like Benson - Representations and Cohomology I or Alperin - Local representation theory or one of the Curtis-Reiner books to learn the relevant theory.

Comment: @mt_: Sorry for the long delay in my reply. Can you point me to the place in one of those books which explains the relevant material to understand your answer?

Comment: @user3533 Benson chapters 1 (background on the representation theory of algebras, Wedderburn's theorem, existence and uniqueness of projective covers, projectives are summands of free modules,...) and 3 (group representations).

Comment: @mt_: Thanks. I found the answer in Benson chapter 1, p. 12, in the discussion under Corollary 1.7.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments, I left an answer as part of the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388033/understanding-a-paper-concerning-the-a-group-ring-an-augmentation-ideal-and-the